# Using cubes in postgresql-simple results in error of "syntax error in multi-row template"

Tags: postgresql, haskell, cube

How are you meant to use [`cube`s](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/cube.html) with [`postgresql-simple`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.4.10.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html)?

At the moment, I'm doing things like

```
query conn "SELECT thing FROM table WHERE coord <@ cube('?, ?') ORDER BY cube_distance(coord, cube('?')) ASC" 
      (In [a, b, c], In [d, e, f], In [g, h, i])
```

which works fine, but feels like a misuse of `In`. It also fails in the case of `executeMany`. For example

```
executeMany conn "INSERT INTO table(thing, coord) VALUES(?, cube('?'))" lst
```

where `lst :: [(String, In [Float])]` fails with a `syntax error in multi-row template`. The equivalent, but less efficient

```
mapM_ (execute conn "INSERT INTO table(thing, coord) VALUES(?, cube('?'))") lst
```

works fine, so I'm assuming this has to do with how `executeMany` organizes the arguments for insertion.

However, the docs make no mention of a `Cube` type, and I can't find an example of its use, so I'm not really sure what I'm *supposed* to do.

Comment: Did you try adding a `Cube` datatype and the `FromField` and `ToField` instances? If you succeed, be sure to contribute to upstream. lpsmith is supportive to these kind of additions.

Comment: @ibotty - [Yes](https://github.com/lpsmith/postgresql-simple/pull/152). I don't need `FromField` for my puproses, and it looks like it would be hard to add, so I left that out (if there's reading I could do to figure it out I'd give it a try, but the non-primitve [`FromField`](https://github.com/lpsmith/postgresql-simple/blob/master/src/Database/PostgreSQL/Simple/FromField.hs) definitions look intimidating enough that I don't want to go in without knowing more about the approach).

Comment: great! Thumbs up! I don't have time to guide you through the non-trivial instances. But be assured, it's not that hard. Pretty sure you had bigger obstacles you overcame in haskell before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this mini-library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-cube-0.1.0.0) I wrote. Once you include that, you can do

```
execute "INSERT INTO table(cube_field, name) VALUES(?, ?) RETURNING id" (Cube [[1, 2, 3]], "Testing")
```

and, more importantly,

```
executeMany "INSERT INTO table(cube_field, name) VALUES(?, ?) RETURNING id"
            [(Cube [[1, 2]], "One"), (Cube [[3, 4]], "Two"), (Cube [[5, 6]], "Three")]
```

There's no `fromField` instance, so you can't select `Cube`s at this point. I won't be adding that because it looks non-trivial, and I don't need it for my use-case, but [patches are definitely welcome](https://github.com/Inaimathi/postgresql-cube).